# Is Objective-C pass-by-value or pass-by-reference?

Tags: objective-c, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Since we always use pointers to define variables, I was wondering if Objective-C is "pass by value", since like Java, the actual value would be passed by using its reference.

However, since it seems to be built up on top of C, would it have all the functionality of C?

Comment: Like C it's pass-by-value.  You can, of course, simulate pass-by-reference by using `&` with a parameter, but it is just simulation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

C does not support *pass-by-reference* and Objective-C, being a strict superset of C doesn't either.

In C (and Objective-C) you can simulate *pass-by-reference* by passing a pointer, but it's important to remember that you're still technically passing a value, which happens to be a the value of a pointer.

So, in Objective-C (and C, for the matter) there is no concept of reference as intended in other languages (such as C++ or Java).

This can be confusing, so let me try to be clearer (I'll use plain C, but - again - it doesn't change in Objective-C)

```
void increment(int *x) {
   *x++;
}

int i = 42;
increment(&i); // <--- this is NOT pass-by-reference.
               //      we're passing the value of a pointer to i
```

On the other hand in C++ we could do

```
void increment(int &x) {
   x++;
}

int i = 41;
increment(i); // <--- this IS pass-by-reference
              //      doesn't compile in C (nor in Objective-C)
```

Comment: This is not true. When you do `somefunction(&var);` var is being passed by reference.

Comment: No it's not. You're still passing the value of a pointer to `var`. It's like doing `void *p = &var; somefunction(p);`

Comment: I still disagree. `function(p)` passes the value of `p`, but `function(&var)` passes the **address** of `var`.

Comment: @Merlevede to convince yourself, write down the signature of `function`. Isn't it `function(void *x)`?

Comment: @Merlevede, by your own definition, Objective-C is not pass by reference. There is no difference between function(p) and function(&var).

Comment: @Merlevede nope. You fail to understand that if you pass `&var`, you're passing the address of `var`, which **cannot** be modified by the function (because is pass-by-value). What can be modified is `var` (by dereferencing the pointer), which is **not** the argument of the function.

Comment: @merlevede I added a C++ example to illustrate the difference. C++ has real references, as Java does. You can pass a variable and the inner function gets access to a reference. In C you can simulate this by _passing a reference_ (i.e. a pointer), which is different from _passing by reference_.

Comment: I had to go and get my Kernigham & Richie (inventors of C) book. You're right, I apologize!!!!

Comment: @Merlevede no problem, it's rather subtle as a difference. I'm glad we sorted this out.

Comment: References is the same pointers at binary level. They just have some conveniences and restrictions for programmes. For example you don't need dereference them every time.

Comment: @Cy4AH, agreed, but from a higher level point of views that makes a whole lot of a difference. For instance, references are immutable, i.e. they don't support pointer arithmetic. The fact that Java only supports references and not pointers is what allows it to be managed language, for example.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: "C++ has real references, as Java does." Java does NOT have pass-by-reference. In Java, "reference" is defined as pointer to an object, which is also what "reference" means in most languages. "C++ reference" is something else entirely.

Comment: So the old terms pass-by-value and pass-by-reference are themselves confusing to people. Agree with newacct. Those terms don't make sense in Objective-C since all pointers to objects and all ivars are called references.

Comment: @newacct Java *only* has pass-by-reference for object types (and pass-by-value for native types). As I previously said, a reference is just a pointer with no arithmetic. Java simply doesn't allow regular pointers, for the sake of memory management.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: Nope. Java has NO pass-by-reference. (Just look around the Internet or Stack Overflow.) And Java has no "object types". The only types in Java are primitive types and reference types.

Answer (score 1):

It is a strict superset of C. 
It does the same as C. 
It's one reason all Objects are actually pointers to structs.