# Objective-C NSArray can't be changed when passed to method in different class

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` and I need to change the order of the items within it. I have written a method that will determine the new order:

```
+(NSArray*)sortProxyForms:(NSArray*)arrayOfForms
{
    NSArray* sortedForms = [arrayOfForms sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(HPSModelFormProxy* a, HPSModelFormProxy* b) {

        return [@(a.ordinal) compare:@(b.ordinal)]; // @(a.ordinal) aka Boxing turns int into NSNumber

    }];

    arrayOfForms = [sortedForms copy]; // DOES NOT WORK

    return sortedOfForms; // WORKS IF ASSIGNED IN THE CALLER

}
```

So, I can pass the NSArray to be sorted into the method.  I call the method like this:

```
[HPSModelUtilities sortProxyForms:_formProxies];
```

If I actually try setting `arrayOfForms` (a reference to `_formProxies`) within the method then once I have returned from the method then the array is unchanged.

However, if I return the sorted array from the method and assign it to the `NSArray` in the calling method then the assignment works:

```
_formProxies = [HPSModelUtilities sortProxyForms:_formProxies]; // _formProxies NSArray is changed
```

`_formProxies` is declared in the calling class, and "HPSModelUtilities" is a different class.

How come the `NSArray` can be changed in the caller, but not changed in the called method, even though it is passed by reference?

Comment: In objective-c, arguments are "pass by value".

Comment: Note that an NSArray is immutable and can't be changed in any case.  What you're apparently talking about changing is the pointer to the NSArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a value into a method it is copied. This is called "pass by value". The arrayOfForms you are passing in is a **pointer** to an **NSArray**. This means that the pointer is copied when passed in. Redirecting this pointer to another instance of an NSArray does not change where the original pointer is pointing.

I would rename your method to `(NSArray*)sortedArrayFromProxyForms:(NSArray*)proxyForms`

If you really want to change where your NSArray reference is pointing in the method. Do it like this.

```
+ (void)sortProxyForms:(NSArray**)proxyForms {
    *proxyForms = sortedForms;
}
```

Comment: Yeah... but, no to that last part.... you should **never have a method that is pass by reference and returns void**.  Utterly pointless.   Just return the `NSArray*` and make the assignment on the caller side.

Comment: @bbum I agree with you, I merely included that solution for completeness. My suggested solution is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a copy of the array reference (subtly different than passing by reference), but then you are changing where that reference points with this line:

```
arrayOfForms = [sortedForms copy];
```

arrayOfForms no longer points to the array instance you passed, but to a different array.  You could pass a pointer of pointer, and change where the caller's pointer is pointing, but for what you are doing, I think the reassignment is fine.

If you'd really like here's what your function would look like with pointer of pointer:

```
+(void)sortProxyForms:(NSArray**)arrayOfForms {
    NSArray* sortedForms = [arrayOfForms sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(HPSModelFormProxy* a, HPSModelFormProxy* b) {

        return [@(a.ordinal) compare:@(b.ordinal)]; // @(a.ordinal) aka Boxing turns int into NSNumber

    }];

    *arrayOfForms = [sortedForms copy]; 
}
```

but I'll add the caveat that this isn't a pattern you see often in objective-c, so I'd avoid it when there are other alternatives available.

Also note when calling this function you need to add the `&` to get the extra level of indirection:

```
[HPSModelUtilities sortProxyForms:&_formProxies];
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, much appreciated - how would I pass a pointer of a pointer?

Comment: The OP is not "passing an array by reference". They are "passing a reference to an NSArray, by value".

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but isn't passing a reference by value a long winded way of saying pass by reference?

Comment: I suppose it's slightly different since it's a copy of the reference, rather than the actual reference, I suppose I'll edit my answer, but the linguistics of programming gets pretty silly at times.

Comment: Just because it accomplishes the same thing, doesn't mean the mechanics behind it are the same. Check this out. (Note that the correct answer is incorrect about Java supporting "pass by reference") http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213197/is-objective-c-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference

Comment: Do not use `(NSArray**)`.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Yeah I thought about it more and it is different than the actual pass by reference in say c++, the difference is subtle, but it's there.

Comment: Look at it this way... Passing a reference to _someclass_ into a method is different from passing in a **copy** of a reference to a reference to _someclass_.